# Designer overriding BindingList defined in UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, bindinglist

I'm using a BindingList in a UserControl to determine update the UI of the Control. `ListChanged` and `AddingNew` events are assigned in the constructor.

I was finding that the BindingList's events were not being fired and after a bit of exploration found that the `onListChanged` and `onAddingNew` event handlers were `null`.

After even more digging I found my problem - that the UserControl's parent form's designer is creating the line:

```
this.myUserControl1.MyBindingList = ((System.ComponentModel.BindingList<MyCustomClass>)(resources.GetObject("myUserControl1.MyBindingList")));
```

Any ideas how to stop the designer from redefining this BindingList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have fixed it - I added the following above the definition of the property in `MyUserControl`

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

Although to be honest I was messing round with a lot of stuff and it may have been any number of things (all to do with serialization of `MyCustomClass` - it was initially Serialized due to the designer complaining about it not being serialized but then this broke other things).

I will wiki-fy this answer in case anybody comes up with a more solid answer!